# UITableView on a UIView with UITapGestureRecognizer (cell selection doesn't work)

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have some problems with using a UITableView on a UIView which haves a UITapGestureRecognizer.
If I click on a UITableViewCell, the background does not change to the selected one (because no touch is received).

I was in the assumption that if you add a childview to a parentview, the childview would be able to handle the touch and that everything would still work. However, this is not the cas. If I tap on a UITableviewCell, the tap is handled by this parentview and the cell is not selected.

I already tried to subclass "UITapGestureRecognizer" to ignore touch events from UITableViewCell:
(monotouch code)

```
public override bool ShouldReceiveTouch (UIGestureRecognizer recognizer, UITouch touch)
        {
            if (touch.View.GetType () == typeof(UITableViewCell))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
```

It's not working because of I click on a cell, "touch.View.GetType ()" returns "UIView" and it's ignored.

Any idea's how I can make my tableview working on a UIView with a UITapGestureRecognizer?

If I remove the "UITapGestureRecognizer" from the parentview, the tableview acts normal.

Thanks Matt

Comment: you want to change selected cell Background change while u tap on it..?

Comment: Yes, but I know how to change the Background for a selected cell. The problem is that when I add my Table on a View with a UITapGestureRecognizer, the Cell will not get "selected" because the tap is handled by the parentview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your UITapGestureRecogizer set the setCancelsTouchesInView property to NO. That should allow your UITableViewCell to receive the touch.

Comment: Wauw, just looked up "setCancelsTouchesInView" and I still have no idea what it exactly does, but it does indeed solve my issue. Quick and easy :-) Thanks!